# Convergence of $\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

Could I have a hint for testing the convergence of the following series please?

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$$

I am very appreciative for your help.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** $$\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}} = e^{-\ln n \ln\ln n} = \frac{1}{n^{\ln \ln n}}$$ and $\ln\ln n> 2$ for $n$ sufficiently big.

Comment: That's fine for me! +1.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: We have $$\log^{\log\left(n\right)}\left(n\right)>n^{\alpha}\Leftrightarrow\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)>\alpha
 $$ and if $n\geq16
 $ holds $$\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)>1.
 $$

Answer (score 0):

Since $(\ln n)^{\ln n}$ is increasing, Cauchy's condensation test may be applied directly: $$2^na_{2^n}=\left(\frac{2}{n^{\ln 2}(\ln 2)^{\ln 2}}\right)^n$$ which rapidly becomes smaller than $2^{-n}$.